# Javascript Ajax call to functions.php using wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi I am following a tutorial on Ajax calls in wordpress. The example has all the code in functions.php but I want to be more organised and include the javascript in a js file.

Here is what I have so far

functions.php

```
//The PHP
function example_ajax_request() {
    // The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via AJAX from the Javascript call
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
        $fruit = $_REQUEST['fruit'];
        // This bit is going to process our fruit variable into an Apple
        if ( $fruit == 'Banana' ) {
            $fruit = 'Apple';
        }
        // Now let's return the result to the Javascript function (The Callback)
        echo $fruit;
    }
    // Always die in functions echoing AJAX content
   die();
}

// This bit is a special action hook that works with the WordPress AJAX functionality.
add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

and in the Javascript file test.js:

```
var ajaxurl = "' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '";

// This is the variable we are passing via AJAX
var fruit = 'Banana';
// This does the ajax request (The Call).

$( ".banana" ).click(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: ajaxurl, // Since WP 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined and points to admin-ajax.php
      data: {
          'action':'example_ajax_request', // This is our PHP function below
          'fruit' : fruit // This is the variable we are sending via AJAX
      },
      success:function(data) {
  // This outputs the result of the ajax request (The Callback)
          $(".banana").text(data);
            window.alert("here");
      },
      error: function(errorThrown){
          window.alert(errorThrown);
      }
  });
});
```

How can: `'action':'example_ajax_request', // This is our PHP function below`

be accessed from the functions.php file?

Comment: WordPress takes care of invoking your PHP function, based on that you _registered_ it as the action to perform with `add_action`. Why would you have any need to access that `action` value now? But it's simply a parameter of the request - so you can access it the same way as you are accessing `fruit`, if you really need it for anything.

Comment: The only issue so far is `var ajaxurl = "' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '";` in your javascript.

Comment: As the code is an error is being thrown I am suspecting that the action where the function example_ajax_request is being called is not being accessed since it is in a different file called functions.php. I am not 100% sure that that is the problem

Comment: So if the whole code is in functions.php this works well but as soon as I am seperating it in functions.php and test.js it is throwing an error. Any idea which part of the code has to be modified?

Comment: @Robert true that is the issue. Can you guide me how to resolve it?

Comment: You can modify your template and add an url as data attribute to some tag. For example to <body> as `data-action="<?= admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>"`. Then in javascript: `var ajaxurl = $('body').data('action');`.